# Update a nested array in AngularFire2

Tags: arrays, nested, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following model for a Firestore document:

```
{
  name: "test",
  isActive: true,
  items: [
   {
     id: "123",
     itemName: "testItem",
     qty: 1
   },
   {
     id: "555",
     itemName: "anotherItem",
     qty: 5
   }]
}
```

Now that Firestore allows to work with nested arrays (via `arrayRemove / arrayUnion`), I am wondering whether this is possible also through AngularFire2.

Or the only way so far is to import Firebase and using it straight ahead? 

Like:

```
this.firestore.collection(<collectionName>).doc(<docID>).update({
 answers: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(<AnswersObject>)
});
```

Moreover is such a model with nested array legit in FIrestore or should it rather be structured in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AngularFire2 does NOT yet support this. You can verify this by checking out the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/document/document.ts).

Or, if you're lazy like me and don't feel like digging through trying to find it on GitHub... what I did to double check was to download the whole repo as a ZIP file, extract, and open folder in VS Code. Searching the whole folder for `FieldValue` or `arrayUnion` returns nothing - those words don't exist in the entirety of the source.

So for right now, you're correct about needing to stick with the default Firebase/Firestore package. And nested arrays are definitely a "legit" thing, but like everything else, when to use it depends on your situation - and I don't feel qualified or experienced enough to evaluate your situation and make a strong recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a while, it seems angular's documentation is always behind. I updated an item the array like this, the array is called `accomodation` and it is within the `day` object.

```
this.data.firestore.doc(`days/${accommodation.day}`)
  .update({
    accommodation: [
      accommodation
    ]
  });
```